# Restart c++ console application using batch doesn't close network connections

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, poco-libraries

I need to restart my application via code and I choose to use a batch file.
When the application starts it creates a batch like this:

```
taskkill /f /im AudioService.exe
TIMEOUT 10
start "AudioService" "AudioService.exe"
```

then I call it from the code (using [Poco Library](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Process.html#16250)):

```
Poco::Process::Args args;
Poco::Process::launch(RESTART_SCRIPT_NAME, args);
```

Now, it works except for the fact that the network connections are not closed and, when the application restart, the Bind() function fails.

Instead, if I run the batch file "by hand" from the Explorer all works as expected: the application and its network connection are killed.

Someone could give me some hint on why this happen?

Comment: Build a proper shutdown mechanism into your application so that you don't have to forcibly kill it.  For example, you could create an event object and exit cleanly if it is set, then provide a `/shutdown` command-line option that sets it.

Answer (score 0):

If an application closes without closing its handles, the OS is responsible for dealing with it.  When the OS decides to close handles is up to the OS, not your application, so you may have to wait a little while for it to clean them up.

You may wish to look up what signal handlers are so that your application can ensure it always cleans up nicely